# Node can't scrape certain pages

Tags: node.js, request, scrape

I don't know if this is something to do with coldfusion pages or what but I can't scrape these `.cfm` pages

In the command line in a directory with `request` run:

```
node> var request = require('request');
node> var url = 'http://linguistlist.org/callconf/browse-conf-action.cfm?confid=173395';
node> request(url, function (err, res, body) { if (err) { console.log(err) } else { console.log('body:', body) }; });
```

I've tried with some other .cfm sites but they work, and am only getting blank results so I don't know what it could be

**Note:** I've also tried doing it the barebones `require('http').get(url,…)` route but I get the same blank result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT ! (finally)

This web server really need to know how to answer to you.
Try this (it work for me)

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  url: 'http://linguistlist.org/callconf/browse-conf-action.cfm?confid=173395',
  headers: {
   'Accept-Encoding':'none'
  }
};
request(options, function (err, res, body) { if (err) { console.log(err) } else { console.log('body:', body) }; });
```

Comment: haha, I just came up with the same conclusion after copying all the headers from my browser. Appreciate it!