# Do I need to use Ajax to not be considered a bot?

Tags: ajax, node.js, bots

**tl;dr: Can someone point me in the right direction for replicating scraping a webpage via Ajax in a Chrome extension...but in node.js?** I'd like to take the relevant tutorials, but am not sure where to start.

==Goal==
As a way to teach myself to code, I'm building a node.js app to pull my Goodreads.com booklist (**using Goodreads' API**) and then search against the San Francisco Public Library's Overdrive catalog (a function that is not contained in Goodreads' API). I'm having a challenge with the second part.

I'm using the Chrome extension Available Goodreads (https://github.com/rhollister/goodreads) as guidance, and I'm making progress - last week, I learned all about regexp (frustratingly fun).

==Problem==
When I use http.request(library_search_url), the site returns a warning that "access to this functionality has been disabled for web-bots." Looking at the extension code, it seems that they use Ajax in a background window to scrape the page.

==Question==
I tried to change how I requested based on some research here (e.g. [Node can't scrape certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862664/node-cant-scrape-certain-pages)), but that didn't work. Do I need to learn express and do something like this (http://mherman.org/blog/2013/10/20/handling-ajax-calls-with-node-dot-js-and-express-scraping-craigslist/) in order to achieve what I want? If not that, is there some other approach I should learn?

(Note: I'm not looking for the code itself - just a direction, so I can go learn what I need to learn.)

Thanks!

*For context, here's the code that makes me think this is Ajax-based scraping:*

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: parseODResults(bookSearchTerms, l, libraryShortName, libraryStr, library.newDesign, searchTerm, url),
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      if (sender) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {
          type: 'FROM_AG_EXTENSION' + id,
          error: error
        });
      }
    },
    xhr: function() {
      return jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Use the api - http://www.goodreads.com/api, scraping their page seems like being against the TOS

Comment: Will edit my initial post to be clearer on this point: I'm using the goodreads api to get the list of books. what the api can't do is query an actual library's overdrive catalog.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is for clients (ie browsers), forget about it. Your issue may be related to the user-agent not being set in `http.request()` so the website doesn't know who is requesting info and rules your request out for *web-bot problem*. `User-Agent` is as standard HTTP header, set it to Firefox's ua for example or any existing browser and it should be good, for example:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'goodreads.com/something',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586'
    }
};
```

However, it's bad practice to scrap html pages when there is an available documented API: http://www.goodreads.com/api You should put that github page aside...

Comment: Thanks @ShanShan! I'll try that and see what happens.

The challenge with that API is that it doesn't do the critical bit: check with Overdrive to actually see what availability is. I do use the Goodreads API to get my list of books, though.